# Confusion between lab data and Origin Summary of Google Page Insight

Tags: performance, optimization, google-developers-console, google-search-console, pagespeed-insights

Any One who Knows are Core web Vitals Details Please help me out with some points.

1. How **Origin Summary** is Different from Lab Data?
2. How Speed Insight Get Origin Summary. Is this the aggregate rating of the last 28 days of the same page or similar pages?
3. I Checked Website Category pages that have the same **LCP** in all of them and in the search console they are inside one section. This is a bit confusing for me to understand how all of these pages have the same Origin Summary but different Lab Data.

I have attached a screenshot for you to see what is confusing me. see LCP in **Lab Data** is 6.6s and **Origin Summary** is showing 3.6s. How it works?????

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### Origin Summary

The timing number / value shown is the average of all of the available **real world** data for that domain, **across multiple pages**.

This is a rolling 28 day average for the **pages** for which it has sufficient data.

The bars show **aggregated** data so you can see how many visitors fall into each category (red = poor, orange = ok, green = good).

As this is an average across all of the data in the [Chrome User Experience (CrUX)](https://web.dev/chrome-ux-report/) data set you can see a low average but still have one page that performs poorly / a certain screen size that performs poorly (which is why they include the aggregate bars as the synthetic test is only at one desktop and one mobile resolution or you may only test the home page and other pages perform poorly).

**SCORING:** This has no bearing on your score and is for information only / to help you identify issues that the synthetic test may not pick up.

### Field Data

If the page being tested had more traffic you might get a break-down by page of the real world data (this would show as "Field Data"). You do not have enough traffic yet for this which is why you only get the origin summary.

The same way that origin data is aggregated and averaged if the page has enough data in the CrUX data-set you will see an average time / value for **that page only**. This is in addition to the origin summary data.

**SCORING:** This has no bearing on your score and is for information only / to help you identify issues that the synthetic test may not pick up.

### Lab Data

This is the **data from the synthetic test you just ran**. This is where your score comes from.

The **origin summary** and **field data** have no bearing at all on the score you see here, they are purely informational.

The score and subsequent action points are generated "on the fly" based on this test run.

**SCORING:** The score you see when you run an audit is calculated from the data gathered **on that run.** No Origin data or Field Data is used in this calculation.

### Example

In the example you gave LCP in lab data (synthetic) is 6.6s and Origin data (real world) is 3.6s.

To understand how this can be the case let's say you have a page that is in the CrUX dataset that Google has three real-world LCP values for. 2s, 3.9s and 4.9s.

Google would then give you the aggregate bars for that page (2s = good, 3.9s = needs improvement and 4.9s = poor) of 33% green (good), 33% orange (needs improvement) and 33% red (poor) based on the [LCP scoring.](https://web.dev/lcp/#what-is-lcp)

These would be your **origin summary** bars.

The time that is displayed for your **origin summary** time would be 3.6s - the average of those three values in the CrUX dataset (((2 + 3.9 + 4.9) / 3) = 3.6.

As for your Lab Data at 6.6s the test has loaded the page with [throttling applied to represent a 4G connection on a mid-tier mobile phone](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/blob/master/docs/throttling.md). It then uses the performance data it gathers to calculate the LCP time.

If you made improvements to the page and re-ran the report the LCP time could drop instantly, as it is based on each run, whereas your origin summary data would take 28 days to completely change to reflect the change.

### So if my data is not in the CrUX dataset how can I identify poorly performing pages.

Let's assume you have a page that does well in the Lighthouse synthetic test but it performs poorly in the real world at certain screen sizes.

Let's also assume there isn't enough data for it to show **Field Data** for that page.

How can you find a page that is ruining your **origin summary**?

For that you need to gather **Real User Metrics (RUM)** data.

RUM data is data gathered in the real world as real users use your site and stored on your server for later analysis / problem identification.

There is an easy way to do this yourself, using the [Web Vitals Library](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/web-vitals).

This allows you to gather [CLS](https://web.dev/cls/), [FID](https://web.dev/fid/), [LCP](https://web.dev/lcp/), [FCP](https://web.dev/fcp/) and [TTFB](https://web.dev/time-to-first-byte/) data, which is more than enough to identify pages that perform poorly.

You can pipe the data gathered to [your own API](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/web-vitals#send-the-results-to-an-analytics-endpoint), or to [Google Analytics](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/web-vitals#send-the-results-to-google-analytics) for analysis.

This is the best way to gather page-specific data when there isn't any / enough data in the CrUX dataset for you to analyse.

Comment: Thanks For Your Answer. It helps me a bit but I got some more questions from your answers. Maybe you can guide me


Which Type of Multiple Page combines for origin summary.?

Suppose I have a home page with some other pages like about, blog posts, categories are separate. How origin will combine it?

How can I see which page is faster and which page is slower that is making the origin summary.?

Comment: As stated it is an average of all pages that Google has (the data is from the CrUX database.) for your whole site. I have answered how they are combined (averages) so not sure what else you want there? If you want to see which pages are faster and slower you could query the CrUX data set, or better yet use [the web vitals library](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/web-vitals) to gather your own Real User Metrics (RUM) data.

Comment: I have updated my answer to be a lot more detailed, hopefully that answers your question, let me know if not.

Comment: yeah, thanks I really appreciate it. But having some confusion more, but I think it will clear after doing some practical.

Comment: Have a go and if you still aren't sure after exploring some more feel free to ask further questions (or a new question if appropriate). I am on the site regularly to help if you get stuck.

Comment: Under 4 LCP is counts moderate and color "orange". But here is showing red color as a poor result. 
https://paste.pics/947aaf9330d63c1d23614e28b12fe679

Comment: Was that Desktop tab by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

**Origin summary** is the aggregate experience of all the pages on your website while Lab data is specific to the page you entered in the field.

1. This means the LCP in the origin summary is aggregate LCP of all the pages on your website.
   Example: let's say, you have 3 pages on your site with LCP on each page as 2, 5, and 7. This means the avg LCP of your website is 4.6s. Now this makes it possible to have a higher LCP: 7 in this case.
2. Refer the example mentioned above on how LCP is calculated. It is the aggregate rating of the last 28 days of all the published pages you have on a domain name.
3. Are you checking just the similar pages?

Comment: It isn't the aggregate of all published pages, it is only pages that have sufficient data in the CrUX dataset. This is why a brand new site will not have any origin data. Also for clarity - lab data is synthetic data from this test whereas "field" data is data in the CrUX database for that page (if there is sufficient data). They do not overlap, no CrUX data is used in the score or in the lab data. i had hoped to make that clear in my answer but I obviously failed :-( I will update my answer for more clarity.