# CLS for a HTML static website with a lot of pages

Tags: html, pagespeed-insights, cls, core-web-vitals

I have a question regarding the latest core web vitals. How exactly it works on a HTML static website with a lot of pages? I made some [tests](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcultureastrology.com%2F&tab=desktop), but the results which I get are really weird. Are these results related to the whole website or only to that page, in my case the frontpage? I also removed a lot of elements to test that, but the result wasn't changes.

And another thing which confuse me .. on one side, google recommend to avoid shifts, but when there are adsense (which is also a product from google), there must be a shift. So, how you are handling that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Your question does not seem to be on topic at SO - perhaps at webmaster

Comment: Re: _"Are these results related to the whole website or only to that page [...]?"_ Results relate to the URL you are submitting. With regard to avoiding layout shift when loading third-party dynamic content, leave a space for the content and then position the content using absolute positioning.

Comment: This question may be a better fit for: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: "lab data" - the URL you entered, this will change if you update the page as it is done "live" and without any caching etc. It is the synthetic test, "field data" - is data in the CrUX data set (real world data from browsers) for the URL you entered (if there is enough data) and is single page. It updates on a 28 day rolling basis so takes a while to change. "origin summary" is the average across all pages that have enough data in the CrUX data set for the whole site.  Yet again taken on a 28 day rolling average. As for Ads - allocated a fixed size container big enough for the ad.

Comment: You may find [this answer I gave detailing the difference between the three useful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65626454/2702894)